# How to disable GTK+ 3.12 client side decorations?

Tags: kde, gtk, kwin

I've updated my Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME/GTK 3.12 (because I want to test drive GNOME and play with some recent GNOME applications), but as a result, all GNOME application now use client side decorations also when running under my default KDE workspace.

Is there a way to disable the GTK+ 3.12 default use of CSD outside GNOME shell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try **gtk3-nocsd**: [article on WebUpd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/08/how-to-disable-gtk3-client-side.html)

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gtk3-nocsd
```

Add the following to your "~/.profile"

```
export GTK_CSD=0
export LD_PRELOAD=/path/to/gtk3-nocsd.so
```

The author an WebUpd8 writes, that Unity doesn't start with that, so you can edit a .desktop file in /usr/share/applications, for example gthumb:

```
/usr/share/applications/gthumb.desktop
```

Add the follwing to "Exec=":

```
env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so
```

so that it looks like this:

```
Exec=env LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/gtk3-nocsd/gtk3-nocsd.so gthumb %U
```

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Its funny though, because what this plugin is that you get the window manager's decoration on top of the GNOME CSDs - so there's still the icon on the top left, the X button on the top right that duplicate the window manager actions. But at least now I can get my customized window buttons.